# Image resolution for iPhone 6/6s and 5/5s

Tags: ios, uiimage, resolution, retina-display

I have images:

1. 320x160 - image.png    (for Iphone 5/5s)
2. 325x190 - image@2x.png (for Iphone 6/6s)
3. 415x200 - image@3x.png 9for iphone 6 plus)

I added image in mainstoryboard. but The simulator is to show the image@2x.png file at iphone 5/5s and iphone 6/6s too. how to make that image.png to show at only iphone 5/5s .
I hope could explain the problem

Comment: FYI - if `image.png` is `320x160` then `image@2x.png` must be `640x320` and `image@3x.png` must be `960x480`.

Comment: but the iPhone 5 takes 325x190 (or 640x320) -image@2х. I want image.png (320x160)

Comment: The iPhone 5 is a 2x retina device. It will always use `@2x` images.

Comment: Iphone 6/6s too?use @2x

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 6/6s is a 2x retina device as is the iPhone 4/4s.

Comment: and iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 use @2x? they have as different resolution. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1x images are only used by non-retina devices. So it's totally normal if 2x images are being used by iPhone 4 and later models.

Only iPhone 2G, 3G and 3GS were non-retina.

You can check device resolutions from here:
http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

And you also got image resolutions wrong. It should look like this:

```
 a x b  (image.png)
2a x 2b (image@2x.png)
3a x 3b (image@3x.png)
```